# Can cysteine alone change pigmentation?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, pigmentation, melanin

According to this graph (from [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18435614)):

[image]

cysteine contributes to pheomelanogenesis, and having a high enough concentration of cysteine makes the shift towards pheomelanin instead of eumelanin. So my question is: theoretically, let's say I would feed my dog a cysteine supplement daily, would that change its coat color over time? If yes, how, and if no, then why not? What am I missing in this process?

***Disclaimer:*** this is just an example, of course I do NOT intend to feed my dog anything at all, it's just a hypothesis. What I want to know is that raising cysteine/glutathione levels can really contribute to pheomelanin production? I know that theoretically, in lab tests a higher cysteine concentration means a higher pheomelanin production, but I am interested in actual living things. If this is possible, it can be a huge breakthrough. If you have the opinion that cysteine alone won't make the difference, than what will? According to the graph attached, that's the only thing making the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surprisingly, it is indeed possible! But, the fact is that the actual process is a bit more complex and might actually require more compounds along with cysteine to give such effects in living beings. First of all, see this image<sup>[1](http://www.ijdvl.com/text.asp?2013/79/6/842/120752)</sup>:

[image: melanin synthesis]

As is clear from the diagram, GSH (glutathione) is also a factor for pheomelanin production, along with cysteine. Another factor on which one might not pay heed is Tyrosinase protein expression. High amount of L-cysteine is thought to decrease the expression of tyrosinase in cells<sup>[2](http://e-ajbc.org/journal/view.php?number=188)</sup> (but since I found just one article, I'd suggest to not pay much attention on this point).

Apart from gene expression, cysteine affects tyrosinase itself too. High concentrations of cysteine and glutathione have been shown to inactivate tyrosinase in cells, and the cause has been suggested to be the thiol-group of GSH and cysteine, which somehow generates oxygen radicals and inactivates tyrosinase<sup>[3](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6192633)</sup>. A concentration of 10mM cysteine is sufficient to inhibit tyrosinase activity in cells<sup>[4](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6203305)</sup>. It is because of these kinds of effects that GSH and cysteine are now being used in cosmetics as skin whitening agents as they, in higher concentrations, inhibit tyrosinase activity and hence, melanin production in skin cells<sup>[5](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2769151/)</sup>.

Just to add, when it comes to gene regulation, then it seems that cysteine has some more effects too. As pointed out by @Chris, eumelanin production in skin is stimulated by a cascade which involves a receptor known as melanocortin-1 receptor (or MC1R). When activated by one of the variants of MSH, typically $\alpha$-MSH, MC1R initiates a complex signaling cascade that leads to the production of the brown or black pigment eumelanin<sup>[6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanocortin_1_receptor)</sup>. Now, a research has concluded that 0.07 mg/ml concentration of L-cysteine greatly reduces expression of MC1R gene, thus literally leaving no way (not really) for eumelanin production<sup>[7](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4092982/)</sup>!

Thus, in short, it is not as simple as "Hey, you want a red skin tone? Here is some cysteine for you!" Cysteine, and other related compounds like GSH, have more complex effect on melanin production than just promoting production of pheomelanin over eumelanin. You can also have a look at [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/54296/19099) answer (by @Chris) for some more information.

*EDIT:* To tell where you're going wrong, I'll make two reaction flowcharts. First, this is (IMO) what you're expecting as an answer:

[image: expected]

But this is what is actually happening:

[image: reality]

The red line is what we're interested in. But as you can see, the diagram is already quite complicated (and expected to get more complicated as more factors are discovered). So, giving a simpler explanation than this would be, very much, impractical or impossible.

**References:**

1. [Malathi M, Thappa DM. Systemic skin whitening/lightening agents: What is the evidence?. Indian J Dermatol Venereol Leprol 2013;79:842-6](http://www.ijdvl.com/text.asp?2013/79/6/842/120752)
2. [The Inhibition Effect of L-cysteine on Melanogenesis in B16F10 Mouse Melanoma Cells; In-Sook An, Ji-Hye Kim, Hoe-sook Yoo, Rui Zhang, Sang-Mo Kang, Tae-Boo Choe, Tae-Jong Kwon, Sung-kwan An, Gi-Yeon Kim](http://e-ajbc.org/journal/view.php?number=188)
3. [The effect of catalase on the inactivation of tyrosinase by ascorbic acid and by cysteine or glutathione; Lindbladh C, Rorsman H, Rosengren E.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6192633)
4. [Inactivation of human tyrosinase by cysteine. Protection by dopa and tyrosine.
   Jergil B, Lindbladh C, Rorsman H, Rosengren E.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6203305)
5. [Mechanisms Regulating Skin Pigmentation: The Rise and Fall of Complexion Coloration; Jody P. Ebanks, R. Randall Wickett, and Raymond E. Boissy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2769151/)
6. [Melanocortin 1 receptor - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanocortin_1_receptor)
7. [Substantial Effect of Melanin Influencing Factors on *in vitro* Melanogenesis in Muzzle Melanocytes of Differently Colored Hanwoo; Touseef Amna, Kyoung Mi Park, In-Kyung Cho, Tae Jeong Choi, Seung Soo Lee, Kang-Seok Seo, and Inho Hwang](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4092982/)

Comment: Nice answer. There is also a genetic component which is important: The status of the MC1R gene. It is responsible for the shift between the eu- and pheomelanin production - how, is not really understood so far. If you have mutations in this gene, this will get less signal into the cell and people are prone for pheomelanin. And I doubt that this can be influenced by diet.

Comment: @Chris Wow I didn't know about this one! Thanks, I'll add it in as soon as I get some citations :)

Comment: Besides, this paper should be interesting for MC1R (and a ton of others, too ;-) ): https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2678743/

Comment: @another'Homosapien' thanks for your great answer! So it seems that my hypothesis isn't just a fairytale after all? To quote myself again: so if I would give cysteine to my dog/kangaroo/pigeon/myself/whatever(the accent is on actual living things, not plants or lab tests) then it could change pigmentation to some degree? This is actually a huge thing. Now I'm not sure how those numbers from those studies would translate to human consumption. In other words: in theory how much cysteine would a human need to reduce the expression of the MC1R and inhibit tyrosinase activity?

Comment: @Chris so you don't think that pheomelanin/eumelanin switch can be induced by diet/supplementation? Do you really think that we humans reached a point in research where we can say :that's it, we just don't know how to make the switch between eu and pheomelanin, we can't influence pigmentation? If you think that pigmentation, either darkening/tanning or lightening can be influenced in any other way and I am dead wrong than could you post some links? If cysteine is the building block for pheomelanin, than why cysteine supplementation won't make a difference? Legit question, I want to know really

Comment: @user30255 I don't think it's that easy. This is a heavily regulated process, that can be influenced by certain drugs. I am not sure (actually I doubt it at the moment) that this can be done by nutrition alone.

Comment: @Chris  What would those specific drugs be? Never heard of any, to be honest. On the flipside, I found Melanotan to increase eumelanin production(the stuff bodybuilders use to get 'tanned'), so I figured there must be something which does the exact opposite. This is scientific banter on my part, I do not recommend nor advocate the use of things like Melanotan or any other potentially dangerous drugs. I just want to investigate all the theoretical solutions to increase pheomelanin as well. So if my cysteine hypothesis might be wrong, care to mention those drugs/substances?

Comment: @user30255 your hypothesis is partly correct. It is partly wrong because this process is not as easy as you are supposing, there are _many_ processes involved in it, and its difficult to get a simple answer for any situation

Comment: @another'Homosapien' could you tell me more about those processes? what am I exactly missing here? I don't mind if this gets complicated

Comment: @another'Homosapien' thanks! sure, take as much time as you need and make it perfect!

Comment: @user30255 does it make some sense now? :)

Comment: @another'Homosapien' yeah that's a good graph, but according to it cysteine is pretty much a super drug which influences everything in there, if it's in abundance. So my question stands: do you think that dietary/supplemental cysteine can influence pheomelanin/eumelanin balance? Not to a drastic measure, but still noticeably. Because right now, in 2017 cysteine seems to be the best bet which could do that, and it could be a breakthrough.

Comment: @user30255 of course it is! That graph was just to mention the complexity at molecular levels. Yeah, cysteine does influence pheomelanin/eumelanin balance quite noticeably. That graph involves _only_ pigmentation factors, if I include other factors as well, its gonna be a _long_ flowchart then ;)

Comment: @another'Homosapien' so you agree with me that dietary/supplemental cysteine excess can influence pheomelanin/eumelanin balance? I heard that l-cysteine, as a supplement is poorly absorbed, what do you think?

Comment: I can't be definitely sure about this point. _[The acetyl group makes cysteine more water-soluble, and functions to speed absorption and distribution on orally ingested cysteine](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.benbest.com/nutrceut/NAC.html&ved=0ahUKEwi34P_g4KDTAhWHMY8KHdWlAHMQFggiMAE&usg=AFQjCNHHxNA3XD-iFMo2818PG41J1gGcAA&sig2=oOBqCY3ag6Hdu3tRg2LrRg)_ yup thats why N-acetyl cysteine is ingested orally for better absorption.